# Convert string to date YYYY-MM

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I tried to convert a string like that "2016-05" in a pyspark dataframe to date format. I know how to convert this string "2016-05-01" to date but when I have just the year and the month, I have en error. Here my df and my code :

```
df.withColumn("date",expr("substring(date, 1, 7)")).show()

+--------------------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|             journal|   date|               title|             content|              author|
+--------------------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|FirstList (Presco...|2016-05|Business For Sale...| Casual dining re...|                null|
|FirstList (Presco...|2016-05|Business For Sale...| Here you go... T...|                null|
```

I use an udf function in order to convert the string column to date :

```
cast_to_date = udf(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m'), DateType())
df = df.withColumn('date', cast_to_date(col('date')))
df.show()
```

But i have this error :

```
    raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %
ValueError: unconverted data remains: -12
```

I know it's a problem with the pattern of the date but I don't know why. Maybe we cannot just have a date field with only year and month ? I watched some topics about that but I never find a solution ... If someone have a solution, thanks for advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a UDF to do this. You can use `to_date` with a format that only includes year and month.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn("date", F.expr("to_date(substring(date, 1, 7), 'yyyy-MM')"))
```